# Match value ends with an emptyline

Tags: c#, regex

The below regex assigns tag as what is between `<` and `>`. It picks the first line alone as value. How to pick all the non-blank lines below each tag and assign to "value" named group?

Regex I used is:

```
(>\s+<(?<tag>[^>]*)>[^$,^\n]*\n(?<value>[^\n]*))?
```

The input file is:

```
> <CompID> 
320856USWA

> <Mop>
169.99398

> <Flag> 
No

> <Location> 
tyt roos>A>0A0.46 
Som 2 rtr Stooms>A>A0>A00 
STOOM tytStockroo>00 
SOM ockro>00 SOM

> <SubLocation> 
5>in 04>tion 2 
M>5uu>T>05 
L>5uhu>M>05 
M>5uu>M>06

$$$$$$
```

The `$$$$$$` is always at the end of the file and is not part of the data.

Comment: Now formatted correctly. Thanks

Comment: Should the last entry contain `$$$$$$`? Or is a blank line a record separator?

Comment: yes last line in the file always have $$$$$$

Comment: Is it part of the data? Do you mean you want to take each non-blank line below each tag as data only?

Comment: $$$$$$ is not part of data. We can simple ignore.

Comment: Yes, I want all no-blank lines below each tag as data and assign to value tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
>\s+<(?<tag>[^>]*)>\s*\n(?<value>[^\r\n]+(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n)[^\r\n]+)*)
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3e%5cs%2b%3c%28%3f%3ctag%3e%5b%5e%3e%5d*%29%3e%5cs*%5cn%28%3f%3cvalue%3e%5b%5e%5cr%5cn%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f!%5cr%3f%5cn%29%5b%5e%5cr%5cn%5d%2b%29*%29&i=%3e+%3cCompID%3e+%0d%0a320856USWA%0d%0a%0d%0a%3e+%3cMop%3e%0d%0a169.99398%0d%0a%0d%0a%3e+%3cFlag%3e+%0d%0aNo%0d%0a%0d%0a%3e+%3cLocation%3e+%0d%0atyt+roos%3eA%3e0A0.46+%0d%0aSom+2+rtr+Stooms%3eA%3eA0%3eA00+%0d%0aSTOOM+tytStockroo%3e00+%0d%0aSOM+ockro%3e00+SOM%0d%0a%0d%0a%3e+%3cSubLocation%3e+%0d%0a5%3ein+04%3etion+2+%0d%0aM%3e5uu%3eT%3e05+%0d%0aL%3e5uhu%3eM%3e05+%0d%0aM%3e5uu%3eM%3e06%0d%0a%0d%0a%24%24%24%24%24%24)

**Details**

- `>` - a `>` char
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `<` -  a `<` char
- `(?<tag>[^>]*)` - "tag" group: 0 or more chars other than `>`
- `>` - `>` char
- `\s*\n` - 0+ whitespaces and then a newline
- `(?<value>[^\r\n]+(?:\r?\n(?!\n)[^\r\n]+)*)` - "value" group:

  - `[^\r\n]+` - 1+ chars other than CR and LF (I am not using `.` since `.` matches CRs in a .NET regex)
  - `(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n)[^\r\n]+)*` - 0+ occurrences of

    - `\r?\n(?!\r?\n)` - a CRLF or LF sequence not followed with another CRLF or LF sequence
    - `[^\r\n]+` - 1+ chars other than CR and LF